# Please help to improve the following sentence

Tags: academic-writing

I am writing the following:

> The length of a standard microblog message approximately equals to the
>   length of a typical newspaper headline and subheading, which makes
>   microblogs a perfect medium to facilitate the produce and consume of
>   news articles.

I find it lengthy (> 30 words), and "to the length of a typical...", where the word "length" appeared before "the length of ....", is there any way to reduce the sentence to make it more readable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The length of a standard microblog message IS approximately THE SAME AS THAT of a typical newspaper headline and subheading, which makes microblogs a perfect medium to facilitate the producTION and consumPTION of news articles.

I would also suggest the claim of a "perfect medium" is a little extravagant and "to facilitate" is unnecessary verbiage. Perhaps "... an ideal medium for the production and ..." would be neater.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is it possible to further reduce "the same as that" to a single or double word?